# factorial of number greater than 12 in (ASSEMLBY MASM)

Tags: assembly, masm

I want to make a program in masm to find the factorial of any number between 1 to 20 but my program is working fine for numbers between 1 - 12 but not greater, and my ma'am told me because you're using eax registers which cannot hold integers values greater than 32 bit so it will store your higher bits will be in edx and lower in eax.
here is my code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.386
.data
.code

main proc

mov eax, 13               ;user input, for 12 fac= 479001600, for 13 incorrect
mov ecx,eax
sub eax,eax
mov eax,1

loop1:
mul ecx
loop loop1

call outdec; it will print whatever in eax

main endp

;--------------------------------------------------------------

outdec proc   ;  Start of my outdec proc working accurately.
push eax
push ebx
push ecx
push edx

cmp eax,0
jge end_if

push eax
mov ah,2
mov dl,'-'
int 21h
pop ax
neg ax
end_if:

mov ebx,10
mov cx,0
rep_loop:
mov dx,0
div ebx
push edx
inc cx
cmp eax,0
jne rep_loop

mov ah,2
prent_loop:
pop edx
add dl,30h
int 21h
loop prent_loop

pop edx
pop ecx
pop ebx
pop eax
ret 
outdec endp

end main
;---------------------------------------------------------------
```

As per ma'am suggestions, I modified my code accordingly but still cant get any thing 
    Here is my modified code, no changes took place in `outdec proc`.

```
main proc

mov eax, 13               ;user input, for 12 fac= 479001600, for 13 incorrect
mov ecx,eax
sub eax,eax
mov eax,1

loop1:
mul ecx
loop loop1

push edx    ; storing numbers of edx in stack
call outdec ; it will print whatever in eax
pop eax     ; supplanting values from stack to eax

call outdec ; again calling outdec
main endp
```

but its doing nothing but printing 0 at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not keeping track of the high dword of the `mul` result for every iteration of your loop. Since you're multiplying "backwards" (starting at 13 and going down to 1), you'll get a product that exceeds 32 bits when you reach `n==2`. At that point `eax` becomes 1932053504 and `edx` becomes 1. But you don't save that 1 anywhere, and then you perform the final iteration of your loop where you'll calculate 1932053504 * 1, which will give you `eax == 1932053504` and `edx == 0`.

Another problem is that you're printing the 64-bit result as two separate 32-bit numbers. That would've been ok if you were printing them in base 2 or base 16 (though you should print `edx` first in that case), but for base 10 you're not going to get the correct output. You need to treat your result as a single 64-bit value when you print it.

Here's an example of what a working implementation could look like, along with some comments to explain the changes:

```
mov ecx, 13       ; n
mov eax,1
xor esi,esi       ; will be used to hold the high dword of the 64-bit product

loop1:
mul ecx           ; multiply the low dword by ecx
xchg esi,eax      ; swap eax and esi temporarily
mov ebx,edx       ; save the high dword of eax*ecx
mul ecx           ; multiply the high dword by ecx
add eax,ebx       ; and add the carry from the low-order multiplication
xchg esi,eax      ; swap eax and esi back
loop loop1

call outdec64     ; it will print whatever is in esi:eax

mov ax,0x4c00
int 0x21


;--------------------------------------------------------------

outdec64:
push eax
push ebx
push ecx
push edx

mov ebx,10
mov cx,0
rep_loop:
xor edx,edx    ; clear edx prior to the high-order division
xchg esi,eax
div ebx        ; divide the high dword of our input by 10, the remainder will carry over to the low-order division
xchg esi,eax
div ebx        ; divide the low dword of our input by 10
push edx       ; and save the remainder for printing
inc cx
cmp eax,0
jne rep_loop

mov ah,2
prent_loop:
pop edx
add dl,30h
int 21h
loop prent_loop

pop edx
pop ecx
pop ebx
pop eax
ret
```